# How to access state variable whilst useEffect on another?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I have to useState declarations:

const [selectedFromYear, setSelectedFromYear] = useState(1900);

const [toYearOptions, setToYearOptions] = useState([])

My component is populating the array years to bind in select options, great, but upon someone selecting say 2015 and this setting selectedtedFromYear I need to repopulate the available toYearOptions to remove any prior to 2015.

I have useEffect listening to selectedFromYear but how do I access/change toYearOptions inside this useEffect?

```
"use client"
import { useEffect, useState, useRef, useMemo } from "react"
import { SearchFilterAPI } from "../../api/searchFilter"
import { IYearsProps } from '../../types/SearchFilterTypes'
import { ISelectOption } from "@/types"

const Years = ({ makeId, rangeId, modelId, handleFromChanged, handleToChanged }: IYearsProps) => {
    const [fromOptions, setFromOptions] = useState<ISelectOption[]>([]);
    const [toOptions, setToOptions] = useState<ISelectOption[]>([]);
    const [selectedFromYear, setSelectedFromYear] = useState<number | null>(1900);
    const [selectedToYear, setSelectedToYear] = useState<number | null>(new Date().getFullYear());
    
    let handleFromChangeLocally = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
        const ele = event.target as HTMLSelectElement;
        setSelectedFromYear(parseInt(ele.selectedOptions[0].value));
        handleFromChanged(parseInt(ele.selectedOptions[0].value));
    }
    let handleToChangeLocally = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
        const ele = event.target as HTMLSelectElement;
        setSelectedToYear(parseInt(ele.selectedOptions[0].value));
        handleToChanged(parseInt(ele.selectedOptions[0].value));
    }
    
    // useEffect(()=>{
    //     let a = selectedFromYear
    //     console.log(toResults);
    //     populateToYearsResults(Math.max.apply(null,
    //         toResults.map(function (item) { return item.value; })), selectedFromYear , toResults);
    // }, [selectedFromYear]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            // Fetch data from api
            let yearsResult = await SearchFilterAPI.getYearsForSelections(makeId, rangeId, modelId);
            let fromResults: Array<ISelectOption> = [];
            let toResults: Array<ISelectOption> = [];
            let fromYear = yearsResult.dateFrom;
            let toYear = yearsResult.dateTo;
            populateFromYearsResults(fromYear, toYear, fromResults);
            populateToYearsResults(toYear, fromYear, toResults);

            setFromOptions([...fromResults])
            setToOptions([...toResults])
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [makeId, rangeId, modelId]);

    return (
        <div className="flex mb-4">
            <div className="w-1/2 h-12">
                <select
                    className="relative w-full searchbar__item rounded-lg border-2"
                    onChange={handleFromChangeLocally}
                    placeholder="Select Year From...">
                    <option key="0" value="0">Select Year From...</option>
                    {
                        fromOptions.map(item => {
                            return (<option key={item.value} value={item.value}>{item.label}</option>);
                        })}
                </select>
            </div>
            <div className="w-1/2 h-12">
                <select
                    className="relative w-full searchbar__item rounded-lg border-2"
                    onChange={handleToChangeLocally}
                    placeholder="Select Year To...">
                    <option key="0" value="0">Select Vehicle Model...</option>
                    {
                        toOptions.map(item => {
                            return (<option key={item.value} value={item.value}>{item.label}</option>);
                        })}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Years;

function populateFromYearsResults(fromYear: number|null, toYear:number|null, fromResults: ISelectOption[]) {
    // Store results in the results array
    let sanitizedFromYear = fromYear ? fromYear : 1900;
    fromResults.push({
        value: sanitizedFromYear,
        label: sanitizedFromYear.toString()
    });
    
    let endYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    if(toYear){
        endYear = toYear;
    }

    for (let index = sanitizedFromYear+1; index <= endYear; index++) {
        fromResults.push({
            value: index,
            label: index.toString()
        });
    }
}

function populateToYearsResults(toYear: number|null, fromYear:number|null, toResults: ISelectOption[]) {
    // Store results in the results array
    let sanitizedToYear = toYear ? toYear : new Date().getFullYear();

    let startYear = fromYear ? fromYear:1900;
    toResults.push({
        value: sanitizedToYear,
        label: sanitizedToYear.toString()
    });
    if(fromYear){
        startYear = fromYear;
    }
    for (let index = sanitizedToYear-1; index >= startYear; index--) {
        toResults.push({
            value: index,
            label: index.toString()
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: By referencing `toYearOptions` and calling `setToYearOptions`? What specific issue are you having?

Comment: "By referencing toYearOptions and calling setToYearOptions? What specific issue are you having?"

But I only want the useEffect to trigger on the change of the selectedFromYear property?

Comment: Ok, not sure what that means. You asked how access the toYear value/setter inside the hook—by using them. You’re not explaining what the problem is.

Comment: Hi Dave, I've updated question to have code from my component. I currently useEffect to call api and get the makes/models for vehicles and the years for these entities. They're stored in my two arrays, toOptions&fromOptions, what I'm trying to achieve is to "recalculate" the years available in toYears when user has selected a from year so that any years before from year are not available for selection in the to year drop down.

My commented out useEffect was where I was attempting to perform the re-populating of the array based on the selectedFromYear property changing. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, but what the **problem** is isn’t clear. When you get the API results set the new state.

Comment: I am fine setting the results from the api call on render if make,range,model change, the problem is I can't change the results, to filter, upon the selectedFromYear change occurring as the useEffect needs reference to the results to change, but if I do this an infinite loop will occur as the results would be changing inside a useEffect referencing the results won't it?

Answer (score 0):

If what you are doing is just computing options based on`selectedFromYear` only, then its better to use `useMemo` instead of state.

```js
const toYearOptions = useMemo(() => {
  // Write your logic to get Array
  return [...Array(10)].map((v, i) => selectedFromYear + i);
}, [selectedFromYear]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access and update the toYearOptions state variable inside the useEffect by simply calling the setToYearOptions function.

```
 const [selectedFromYear, setSelectedFromYear] = useState(1900);
 const [toYearOptions, setToYearOptions] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
// Filter the options to remove years before selectedFromYear
const filteredOptions = toYearOptions.filter(year => year >= 
selectedFromYear);

// Update the toYearOptions state with the filtered options
setToYearOptions(filteredOptions);
}, [selectedFromYear]);
```